# Is it possible to train an AI to classify an image using only 1 image?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I started studying machine learning in python a few days ago and I was trying some examples online when I decided to try it for myself using a custom dataset.

However, I noticed that most datasets involve images that are taken from camera photos composing of hundreds, if not thousands of images with the same target image.

If I create a custom icon in Photoshop, do I need to take a picture of my monitor a thousand times to achieve this? Is it possible to train an AI using only a single PNG file?

My goal right now is to let the AI do object detection on another big image and it needs to find the custom icon inside the image, kind of like Finding Waldo. All of which are digital images straight from Photoshop though, so I don`t know if it is possible.

Right now, I am using a python-based Computer Vision library called ImageAI.

Comment: Related: [One-shot learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-shot_learning).

Comment: How is creating an icon in photoshop related to ML?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I simply meant that both my datasets and evaluation images are photoshop created, not images taken from camera of a real world object that`s all.

Comment: A long time ago, before everything in vision was called "AI", there was [OpenCV's feature matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html) to solve such problems

Comment: How much can this "icon" you want to find change? Is it a pixel-by-pixel identical copy? Will it be distorted by lighting, shadows, perspective, being printed on a rumpled T-shirt? Are your images all screenshots? Or all top-down pictures of a working area? Or could there be some underwater photos of a coral reef, with a dolphin sporting your icon as a tattoo?

Comment: I plan on using top-down pictures of a working area (display the image on a tablet). I just wonder if it is possible to skip taking pictures of my screen a thousand times for training. I have also tried OpenCV`s template matching and SSIM compare, and plan on listing out the results of the three

Comment: @GoodDeeds After reading some articles and papers, I believe One-shot learning so far answers my question. Thank you. Could you post that as an answer so I can mark it? Thank you again

Comment: Great to hear. I don't have have enough material right now to expand it into a proper answer, but you are welcome to write one yourself and answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data preparation strategy called Data Augmentation.
There are mainly two types of Augmentation

- Linear Transformation
- Affine Transformation

Here is a good white paper 
http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2017/pdfs/300.pdf